# Slow free() on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c, gcc, free

I am debugging a piece of audio software needing low latency yet depending on running free of xruns. I have reduced the problem to be in a call to `free()`. It is a fairly large block of data to be freed.

This is on a Raspberry Pi 3 using Linux and gcc (target armhf). The software is using pthread and realtime priority. I need to allow 21 ms latency to be able to use the software without modification. If commenting out the `free()` call I am able to run at 5 ms without xruns.

Is there any way of speeding up the `free()` call? Maybe using some kind of garbage collection mechanism running in a low prioritised thread?

**Update**

After some investigation it turns out the `free()` is actually running in a low prioritised thread already. The only thing happening in the realtime thread is simultaneous data transfer to and from the audio device (four channels in and four out). Despite this, the `free()` is causing xruns. This makes me wonder if `free()` cannot be interrupted even by a realtime scheduler on an armhf target? The size of the object to be freed is 2 MB.

There might still be something going on that I have overlooked. I am not the original author of this source code so I don't yet have full understanding of it.

Comment: You shouldn't malloc or free in your main audio thread. Can you offload the free to another thread or just keep a big chunk of memory allocated for all your needs?

Comment: @tkausl +100 General purpose memory allocation in a real-time thread sounds very wrong.

Comment: I have yet to discover the design of this piece of software. It's not my code so I don't yet understand the ins and outs. I have been thinking of just pre-allocating everything as you mention, though it is hard to say in advance how much you will need. I will look into offloading to another thread. Thanks!

Comment: Well, after some investigation it turns out that the `free()` is actually running in a non-realtime thread. Despite this, I get xruns on the realtime thread taking care of the audio. This makes me wonder if `free()` is actually occupying the cpu until it's done even if there is a realtime thread waiting to be scheduled?

Comment: @Johan `free()` is almost certainly holding one or more locks while doing its work.  If your main realtime thread makes **any** use of `malloc()` or `free()` or any of their variants (`new` and `delete` in C++), your main realtime thread will block waiting for the `free()` to run.  You probably should also look for code that indirectly makes such calls.  Stdio functions (that uses `FILE *`) often use `malloc()` and `free()` indirectly, for example. Any C++ code, especially from inexperienced developers, often does too.

Comment: So if the realtime thread is not doing any `malloc()`, it will not be blocked by `free()`, but as soon it calles `malloc()` it will start getting blocked by `free()`... Is that what you mean? If so, I need to dig deeper, but I don’t think there is any `malloc()` going on in the realtime thread, directly or indirectly.